# PCRE open-ended range & partial matching

Tags: c, regex, pcre

Using PCRE from C, given the regex /^a{1,3}$/ and the string "aa", pcre_dfa_exec() returns 1 indicating that the string matches.

What I need is to be able to determine that the string does not exhaust the regex, and that there is room for further characters in the string which might potentially also match (ie "111").

I can't find an API for this in PCRE. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you give examples of other strings and what the results should be?

Comment: All other rules should be the same as normal matching. eg 'b', 'ab', 'aaaa' should not match, 'a', 'aa' should indicate that they match but are not exhaustive, and 'aaa' should match exactly. PCRE_PARTIAL almost does this, except it considers 'aa' to be an exact match.

Comment: That's because `aa` IS an exact match. Your regexp says it matches 1, 2, or 3 a's. I'm not sure what you mean by "which might potentially also match".

Comment: If you want to know if it's exactly `aaa` use `/^a{3}$/`

Comment: I get that, but I don't have a static regex. I can't simply use a different regex. What I mean is "aa" is an exact match, but so would be "aaa". I could add further characters to the test string and it wouldn't necessarily fail to match. I can check this in Java using requireEnd (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#requireEnd()). Does PCRE not have anything similar?

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong and #requireEnd actually doesn't appear to give any useful info in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You cant do that using pcre or any other regexp matching engine either for that matter. Consider the regexp `a+`, there is no string for which the regexp is exhausted. For most regexps, there is an infinite number of strings that will match it.

However, if you limit your problem to regexps that only match a finite number of characters you could solve your problem. You would first generate all strings that satisfy a regexp and then check that the specified string is the longest one among them.

You could use this perl module: [Regexp:Genexp](http://search.cpan.org/~bowmanbs/Regexp-Genex-0.07/lib/Regexp/Genex.pm) Or use the Python solution [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.python/vG4wWESu7oI/eBRsgspfO_AJ).